# CP down, 504 error

Tags: control-panel, ee3

I have a huge problem with performance of CP (EE 3.3.4). Sometimes I can see the 504 error (at the same time PHP works like crazy!). New Relic says that I use all php sources and probably that's why CP is down.

Did you have similar problems? If so, what shoud I'm looking for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, in your config.php file, set this `$config['allow_extensions'] = 'n';`
If your cpu load drops off, you have an issue with an addon extension.

Second, you should be able to dial in on what is causing the issue using New Relics APM. Highlight the area where the load ramps up, then view the transactions and see what is taking the most time, or if there is a query that is taking a long time or running like 200 times in a row. New Relic is a very powerful tool and has helped me trace many different issues, which often lead to something weird happening in an addon.